# String Manipulation to Validate Phone Number

Tags: javascript, string

**EDIT: I am not able to use regular expressions since this is for a class and my professor would like us to learn the value of string manipulation!**

I need to use string manipulation to validate phone number from a form. The logic I need to use (for a class requirement) is to compare the phone number against 2 strings and output a new string. Then compare a new string against 4 mask phone number types to validate as true.

For some reason, its only printing 'dddddddddd'. Did I use the wrong type of loop? Am i closing it too early? please see below:

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function validatePhone()
    {
        // kb- this is the phone number the end user will input into the form
        phoneString = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
        // this is a number string I will use to compare the phone number against to confirm if it is a number
        var numberString = "1234567890";
        // kb- this is an operator string I will use to compare the phone number against to confirm if it has symbols in it such as (,), or -
        var operatorString= "()-";
        //kb- this is a dummy string I will be creating through this function
        var dummyString= "";
        // kb- these are the 4 mask ID phone numbers. If the phone number does not fit one of these masks, it will not be a valid phone number
        var mask1= "dddddddddd";
        var mask2= "(ddd)ddddddd";
        var mask3= "(ddd)ddd-dddd";
        var mask4= "ddd-ddd-dddd";
        console.log(phoneString);
    // kb- this is my for loop to go through the entire phone number string character by character
        for (var i=0; i <phoneString.length; i++)
        {
            var c = phoneString.charAt(i);

        //kb- if the character in the phone string is true (a #), please add a D to the dummy string
         if (numberString.indexOf(phoneString) != -1)
            {
                dummyString +="d";
            }

            // kb- if the character is not a number, if it is a '(', please add that to the dummy string
            else if (operatorString.indexOf(phoneString) ==0)
            {
                dummyString +="(";
            }

            //kb- if the character is not a number or a '(', if it is a ')',please add that to the dummy string
            else if (operatorString.indexOf(phoneString) ==1)
            {
                dummyString +=")";
            }

            //kb- if the character is not a number, a '(' or ')', but it is a '-', please add that to the dummy string
            else if (operatorString.indexOf(phoneString) ==2)
            {
                dummyString += "-";
            } 
        } 
        // kb- please print this to the console 
        console.log("dummyString is" + dummyString);
        // if the final dummy string matches 1 of the 4 mask IDs, alert as a true phone number

        if (dummyString == mask1 || dummyString== mask2 || dummyString ==mask3 || dummyString == mask4)
        {
            alert (dummyString);
        }
        return;
    }
```

HTML:

`form name= "PizzaForm">
    <input type= "text" name="phone">
    <input type = "button" value = "Submit Order" onClick = "validatePhone()"/>
    </form>`

Comment: Did u tried to validate phone using regexp? if not, just edit your answer with all acceptable phone masks, and I will try to help you

Comment: I am not allowed to use regexp since this if for a class

Comment: Sorry, but why are you not allowed to use regexp? Don't understand

Comment: Dump teacher behaviour

Comment: because my professor just won't let us for this assignment :(

Comment: Given the input element value is "2845": Your syntax `numberString.indexOf(phoneString)` is specifically looking for "2845" in the string "123456789". This won't do what you expect it to do. Yin Cognyto's answer is putting you on the right track.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Hopefully it will solve the whole issue, if the rest of the process is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression just looking at the code without running it is that you should replace `phoneString` in your first `if` check with `c` (like this: `if (numberString.indexOf(c) != -1)`...). After all, it's *each character* (aka `c`) in the `phoneString` you want to test, not the entire `phoneString`, right?

Comment: You're welcome, friend. You can of course skip it if you like, but generally it's nice to mark the answer that helped you the most as the accepted answer. An upvote won't do any harm either :)